# Python - Num1 1 not defined

Tags: python

```
def to_numbers():
  num1 = str(raw_input('Enter a string number?\n'))

for value in num1:
  try:
    print '%s as an int is %d' % (str(value), int(value))
  except ValueError, ex:
    print '"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (value, ex)
```

Was wondering if I can code this correctly. Received `num1 not defined` error.

Comment: You never call your function. Furthermore, `num1` is local to your function, and you never return a value...

Comment: Keep an eye on your indentation

Comment: @Stratton - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `num1` in the function `to_numbers` (otherwise, you cannot use this value outsize of `to_numbers`). Then you need to call `to_numbers` in order to define `num1`, as follows:

```
def to_numbers():
    num1 = str(raw_input('Enter a string number?\n'))
    return num1

num1=to_numbers()
for value in num1:
    try:
        print '%s as an int is %d' % (str(value), int(value))
    except ValueError, ex:
        print '"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (value, ex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is very sensitive when it comes to indentation, so make sure you indent your code correctly to get expected results. You are getting num1 as not defined error as num1 scope is in method to_numbers() and for loop is not in to_numbers() scope, hence error.

Deleting line between num1 assignment and for loop and indenting for loop to be in sync (spaces) just as num1 will make num1 accessible in to_numbers().

As I am using Python 3.x, I have to update few syntax like adding brackets to print statements and using as keyword for naming exception instance but your logic remains same.

```
import platform

## Your method
def to_numbers():
  num1 = str(input('Enter a string number?\n'))
  for value in num1:
    try:
      print ('%s as an int is %d' % (str(value), int(value)))
    except ValueError as ex :
      print ('"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (value, ex))

## Print Python version for your reference
print("Python version : " + platform.python_version())
## Calling your method
to_numbers()
```

Sample Run

```
Python version : 3.6.1
Enter a string number?
1234567890abcdefgh
1 as an int is 1
2 as an int is 2
3 as an int is 3
4 as an int is 4
5 as an int is 5
6 as an int is 6
7 as an int is 7
8 as an int is 8
9 as an int is 9
0 as an int is 0
"a" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
"b" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'
"c" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'
"d" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'
"e" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
"f" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
"g" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
"h" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert tabs so the for is inside the function. Else, you just have a function which reads a value and a `for` outside of it, which cannot access to `num1`.